# Memory access error in calling c++ function from managed C# code

Tags: c#, c++, access-violation

I have a managed C# program that calls a function in an unmanged C++ dll. I get an error about memory. I have debugged tirelessly but can't seem to find a solution. Please advice me how to pass the right data format from C# to the called C++ function.

Here is what I have:

**ERROR:**

```
" at Frame_Processor.ProcessFrames(Frame_Processor* , SByte* , SByte* , Int32 , SByte* ) "   
     ***-- this is the  unmanged C++ function that is called.***

" at Frame_Processor_Wrapped.ProcessFrames(String framesPath, String datasetPath, Int32 frameCount, String keyName)" 
    ***-- this is the manged function that called it.***
```

it seems that the format of the arguments is the problem. SByte*/string. Please advice.

NEW EDIT:

**C# (Managed code)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //test
            string id = "abcd";
            string in = "C:\\input\\";
            string out = "C:\\output";
            int count = 10;

            Frame_Processor_Wrapped fp = new Frame_Processor_Wrapped();
            fp.ProcessFrames(in, out, count, id);
        }
```

**C++/CLI code (with Marshaling)**    -- AKA Frame_Processor_Wrapped

```
 void Frame_Processor_Wrapped::ProcessFrames(System::String^ in, System::String^ out, int count, System::String^ id)
        {               
            StringConversion ^convert = gcnew StringConversion();

            //convert System.String to char*
            char* in_char= convert->myStringToChar(in);             
            char* out_char= convert->myStringToChar(out);
            char* id_char= convert->myStringToChar(id);

            frameProcessor->ProcessFrames(in_char, out_char, count, id_char);                               
        }
```

*

```
/* Conversion Class*/   
StringConversion::StringConversion() {}

        char* StringConversion::myStringToChar(System::String^ str)     {
            System::IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str);         return
     static_cast<char*>(ptr.ToPointer());   }
```

*

**C++ DLL (unmanged code)**

```
void Frame_Processor::ProcessFrames(char* in, char* out, int count, char* id)
    {
        //use the parameters here for something (w,x,y,z varaibles)
        w = out;
        x = in;
        y = count;
        z = id;

        //do something
        RunProcessFrames();
    }
```

I get run-time error about memory access.

Comment: You'll have to do your own marshaling to get strings to go between native and managed, which will involve writing C++/CLI to do the interop.  Here's a starting point: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22e4dash.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22e4dash.aspx).

Comment: It is doubtful that one can help you unless you reveal declarations of `Frame_Processor.ProcessFrames` on both managed and unmanaged sides.

Comment: thanks, I have made edits to include the code.

Comment: The code leaks memory, but nothing that would explain an AVE.  Surely the bug is located in RunProcessFrames().  Make sure to enable unmanaged code debugging.

Comment: @nikk  have you found solution of your problem

Comment: Yes, I did. It was about two years ago though, so I don't quite remember the exact specifics. But you want to ensure that you are correctly marshaling data types from one language to the other, and pay attention to size of char being allocated (marshaled) if using string/char in your arguments.